# FFMPEG | Rearrange crop

Tags: ffmpeg, crop

I need to "Encrypt" video with FFMPEG.

I did a lot of research and I did not find a solution to my problem :(

Is it possible to do that?

What I need:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image][image]
<sub>Before and after image examples.</sub>

Use [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop), [hstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack), and [vstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex \
"[0:v]crop=iw/2:ih/2:0:0[lt]; \
 [0:v]crop=iw/2:ih/2:ow:0[rt]; \
 [0:v]crop=iw/2:ih/2:0:oh[lb]; \
 [0:v]crop=iw/2:ih/2:ow:oh[rb]; \
 [lb][lt]hstack[top]; \
 [rt][rb]hstack[bottom]; \
 [top][bottom]vstack" \
-c:a copy output
```

Comment: had to do something similar, don't think I would have figured it out (or even been sure it was possible!) via the official docs. following your example, my video was re-arranged perfectly on the first try. thank you!